# how do you run a c program in cmd

Tags: c

I've opened the **cmd in windows** and I've created a directory by using `md` command. After that I've opened a text file via `notepad <name>`, wrote my program and gave `.c` extention while saving the file.

How can I compile and run my C program to get an output? I've also other programs in my directory: how can I create .exe files for all of them?

Answer (score 5):

Free (beer-free, not necessarily speech-free) C compilers for Windows include (from memory so there may be others):

- MinGW (Minimalist GNU for Windows)
- MSYS
- Cygwin
- Eclipse CDT (which uses GNU under the covers I think)
- Borland C++ (from their BDN museum site)
- Visual C++ Express

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this c compiling handout](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/handouts/cstepbystep/index.html) can be of any use.

It shows all the steps needed to create a c based executable file.

Answer (score 2):

You need a compiler - are you using Visual Studio? GCC? The compiler you are using should come with some simple setup instructions to help to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend if there is no reason to use MS windows, try linux.

http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/intrepid/beta

The development environment is free.